# Built Vue Application Allows Webpack View of Source

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have recently built my Vue application using the command:

`npm run build`

Where the files have been built and placed inside the `dist` folder.

I included a `console.log('Special log')` in my Environment.vue file as I need to check on something in the Production environment.

In the devtools, that console.log is shown:

`Special log                                       Environment.vue: 101`

And to my surprise, when I click on that `Environment.vue: 101` log, I am shown the full source code of the `Environment.vue` file.

I have double checked the dist folder and I did not see the Environment.vue file there.

When I hover over the `Environment.vue` in the console, I see the following:

`webpack:///src/views/Environment.vue:101`

I am unsure why the file's source code is being shown, when the application deployed has already been coming from the build (dist) folder.

Has someone encountered such issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have source maps enabled?

Comment: I had the source maps disabled. Does it reside in a different setting / file in vue-cli? I have it in the vue.config.js under the module.exports.